# Wordpress add child pages to menu during runtime

Tags: wordpress

I want to build a large menu(more than 100 items) in admin panel, there are server post variable limit. So i have created a menu with parent pages only. I want to add child pages to parent pages in menu during runtime. I am using wp_nav_menu function. Is it possible with walker class or any other solution.